# Изменение значения параметра объекта в QML из потока

Tags: c++, qt5, qml

Есть qml файл в котором нарисован датчик, содержимое примерно такое:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.1

Window
{
    visible: true
    id : mainScreen

    width: 720
    height: 400

    Rectangle
    {
        id : main_cadran
        anchors.fill: parent
        color : "black"
        Component.onCompleted: {
            forceActiveFocus();
        }
        visible: true

        property real speed_value : 0;


        Rectangle
        {
            id: top_line
            width : main_cadran.width
            height : main_cadran.height * 0.6
            color: "#000000"

            anchors
            {
                horizontalCenter : parent.horizontalCenter
                top : parent.top
            }

            RoundGauge
            {
                anchors
                {
                    left : top_line.left
                    right : top_line.horizontalCenter
                    top : top_line.top
                    bottom : top_line.bottom
                }

                unit: "value"
                currentValue: main_cadran.speed_value
                digitalFont.pointSize: 20
            }
        }



    }
}
```

У объекта RoundGauge есть свойство currentValue, отвечающее за текущее значение прибора.

На C++ создается поток с функцией обратного вызова, получающей данные с сервера. Задача состоит в том, чтобы эта функция обратого вызова могла корректировать значение currentValue в qml, меняя показания прибора.
Подскажите, как это возможно реализовать. а лучше приведите пример подобной реализации.
Спасибо!

Comment: Функция из принимающая значения во втором потоке должна эмитить сигнл с новым значением, с currentValue должно обновлятся из слота в UI потоке

Answer (score 0):

Приведу пример реализации.

Класс dataOutput вырабатывает с заданной периодичностью сигнал (sigData(int)) с данными которые будем получать в QML.

dataOutput.h:

```
#ifndef DATAOUTPUT_H
#define DATAOUTPUT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>

class DataOutput : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    int currentData;
    QTimer *timer;
public:
    DataOutput(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~DataOutput();
signals:
    void sigData(int currentdata);
private slots:
    void slTimeout();
};

#endif // DATAOUTPUT_H
```

dataOutput.cpp:

```
#include "dataoutput.h"

DataOutput::DataOutput(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent), currentData(0)
{
    timer = new QTimer();
    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &DataOutput::slTimeout );
    timer->start(2000);
}

DataOutput::~DataOutput()
{
    timer->stop();
    if(timer != nullptr) delete timer;
}

void DataOutput::slTimeout()
{
    ++currentData;
    emit sigData(currentData);
    timer->start(2000);
}
```

Создаем QQmlContext которому указываем объект (DataOutput) к которому необходимо получить доступ из QML и задаём имя по которому будем к нему обращаться в QML.

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include "dataoutput.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    QQmlContext *ctxt = engine.rootContext();
    DataOutput dataoutput;
    ctxt->setContextProperty("dataOutput", &dataoutput);

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

Теперь можно в QML получать сигнал от класса DataOutput. Для этого создаем соединение и обрабатываем полученный сигнал.

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    property real value: 0;
    Text {
        anchors.fill: parent
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        text: "Value: " + value
    }
    Connections {
        target: dataOutput
        onSigData: {
            value = currentdata;
        }
    }
}
```